# Why the list of a object returned from hibernate is empty?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Well, I'm here again. In the project that I work, I have faced a problem, sametimes I solve it with another way to do it. But in a ManyToMany relationship, I don't know to make it. When I use the find method of EntityManager and it's returned a object, and if this object has a list of other objects, sometimes this list come empty even when I saved the object filled the list.

The classes:

```
public class EquipeCategoria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private ESexo sexo;
    private ECategoria categoria;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private Equipe equipe;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private EquipeJogo equipeJogo;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<Dirigente> dirigentes;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<Atleta> atletas;
    @ManyToOne
    private Modalidade modalidade;
    @ManyToOne
    private Prova prova;
    // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Dirigente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String doc_prof;
    private String nome;
    private EFuncao funcao; // EFuncao
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    private List<EquipeCategoria> equipes;
    @ManyToOne
    private Equipe equipe;
    // getters and setters
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: You have not posted the relevant code, but it looks like you have not read about the *Fetch* modes

Comment: I try use EAGER, but don't worked.

Comment: It would help if you could post part of code that you use to save and find the entity you're having problems with.